# Where can I find lorenz curve of countries?

Tags: macroeconomics, statistics

I have been able to find values of Gini coefficient but have not been able to find their corresponding lorenz curves.

Answer (score 7):

[Knoema](https://knoema.com/crmndag/gini-coefficient-and-lorenz-curve-around-the-world) has visualizations of Lorenz curve for a large number of countries, however note if you are doing some research it is expected you will make your own visualizations based on the data.

Comment: Note that this particular visualization doesn't give you much more information than the Gini coefficient, potentially even less. It plots exactly 5 percentiles, meaning everything in the top 20% is thrown together. So all the plots look visually the same and you can't really see whether there is 20% fairly wealthly people or just 1% who one most of everything. If the Gini coefficient was computed on more finely grained data it might still contain more information.

Comment: @quarague I more or less agree but OP requested these visualizations, maybe you should comment this under the Q